# Installing Boost on CentOS 6.5 (Rocks 6.1.1)

Tags: centos, centos6.5, boost, linux, libboost

I have a Rocks 6.1.1 (with CentOS 6.5) installed on a VM, and I'm trying to get Boost installed on it.
I tried doing `yum install boost-devel`. However, it complains about missing dependencies:

```
   Error: Package: boost-devel-1.41.0-18.el6.i686 (Rocks-6.1.1)
           Requires: libboost_serialization.so.5
   Error: Package: boost-graph-1.41.0-18.el6.i686 (Rocks-6.1.1)
           Requires: libicuuc.so.42
   Error: Package: boost-devel-1.41.0-18.el6.i686 (Rocks-6.1.1)
           Requires: libboost_math_tr1l.so.5
   Error: Package: boost-devel-1.41.0-18.el6.i686 (Rocks-6.1.1)
           Requires: libboost_prg_exec_monitor.so.5
   ...
```

How do I get `libboost` installed? Maybe I'm missing a repository, or something like that (a silly mistake).

Thank you very much.

Comment: A little bit further information please? I have the last Rocks release (6.1.1). It's fresh, there isn't anything else to upgrade that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

My guess (not able to test a Rocks VM build at the moment) is that the Rocks 6.1.1 install doesn't include the latest EPEL release package (for EL6), which includes libboost and its dependencies. You can get the latest package [here](http://mirror.umd.edu/fedora/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm). Hopefully installing that package and then running a `yum install boost-devel` will work for you.

Comment: I tried this, and I still get the same error.